# Shell Linux : grep exact sentence with NULL character

Tags: linux, shell, null, grep

I have a file like

```
key\0value\n
akey\0value\n
key2\0value\n
```

I have to create a script that take as argument a word. I have to return every lines having a key exactly the same than the argument.

I tried

```
grep -aF "$key\x0"
```

but grep seems to do not understand the \x0 (\0 same result). Futhermore, I have to check that the line begins with "$key\0"

I only can use sed grep and tr and other no maching commands

Comment: `grep -aw "^$key" file` (to match only at the start of the line) or `grep -aw "$key" file` (to match anywhere in the line). Assuming the variable `key` has the key to match.

Comment: it does not work enough :if there is two keys with "$key" at the begin and followed by other characters, it will match with theses two. I try to get the line having the exact key and followed by \x0

Comment: If you both need it anchored to the beginning *and* not being matched as a regex then you can only do that with the `\0` anchor if you can be sure each "line" only has one key/value pair and only one '\0` on the line. And actually I'm not sure you can do that without escaping the key manually.

Comment: I suggest not using the term NULL to refer to the null character. In C, `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. Mixing up null pointers and null characters is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To have the \0 taken into account try :

```
  grep -Pa "^key\x0"
```

it works for me.

Comment: This will match values and partial keys too.

Comment: With the perl-style -P it takes \0 into account. He can refine from there.

Comment: I saw that the -P match the \0, but if the key contains regex it will match with it. I need to match with the exact key.

Comment: Only the first line of your example should be a match right ?  try  **^** instead of **$**   ...  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: it work if the key is only with alpha num characters. In my case, the key can be "k.+" for example. the -P will enable the perl regex and then will match with all the keys begining with 'k'. It is why I cannot use the -P option :/

Comment: So for k.+  doing   grep -Pa "^k\.\+\x0"

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `sed`

`sed` will work:

```
$ sed -n '/^key1\x00/p' file
key1value
```

The use of `\x00` to represent a hex character is a GNU extension to `sed`.  Since this question is tagged `linux`, that is not a problem.

Since the null character does not display well, one might (or might not) want to improve the display with something like this:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(akey\)\x00/\1-->/p' file
akey-->value
```

#### Using `sed` with keys that contain special characters

If the key itself can contain sed or shell active characters, then we must escape them first and then run `sed` against the input file:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v script '/^%s\\x00/p' "$(sed 's:[]\[^$.*/]:\\&:g' <<<"$1")"
sed -n "$script" file
```

To use this script, simply supply the key as the first argument on the command line, enclosed in single-quotes, of course, to prevent shell processing.

To see how it works, let's look at the pieces in turn:

- `sed 's:[]\[^$.*/]:\\&:g' <<<"$1"`

  This puts a backslash escape in front of all sed-active characters.
- `printf -v script '/^%s\\x00/p' "$(sed 's:[]\[^$.*/]:\\&:g' <<<"$1")"`

  This creates a `sed` command using the escaped key and stores it in the shell variable `script`.
- `sed -n "$script" file`

  This runs `sed` using the shell variable `script` as the `sed` command.

#### Using `awk`

The question states that `awk` is not an acceptable tool.  For completeness, though, here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F'\x00' -v k=key1 '$1 == k' file
key1value
```

Explanation:

- `-F'\x00'`

  `awk` divides the input up into records (lines) and divides the records up into fields.  Here, we set the field separator to the null character.  Consequently, the first field, denoted `$1`, is the key.
- `-v k=key1`

  This creates an `awk` variable, called `k`, and sets it to the key that we are looking for.
- `$1 == k`

  This statement looks for records (lines) for which the first field matches our specified key.  If a match is found, the line is printed.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, i suspected an other command should work :)

Comment: The issue is that "$ sed -n '/^key1\x00/p' file" will interpret key as a regex (in the case of "key" is not a simple string but contains . or other special characters). Futhermore, I cannot use awk (it is why it seems hard)

Comment: @Arthur OK.  I added a section for using `sed` with keys that contain special characters.  Let me know if it works for you.