# Match with fixed string in sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, null

I have to use `sed` to match with a fixed string.

I have a pseudo database in a file like:

```
key\x0value
keyyy\x0value
```

If I whish to get the first line only if i use as argument "key" and not "ey" for example.
* Match with key : "key"
* Do not match : "k", "ke.", "ey", ... : No regex, no partial search, only "key"

I cannot use `awk` and the string MUST contain a `\x0` at the end of the key.
It seems that I cannot use grep neither because it doesn't handle the \x0 or \0

The problem is that I cannot both ask to match /^key\x0/ and do not interpret key with a regex.

Finaly, my sript will take only ONE argument : the EXACT KEY TO MATCH.

Comment: it is not very clear what you mean. Could you post some example with your current output and the desired one? For example, if you say `sed -n '/key\\x0value/p' file` this will print the lines containing `key\x0value` (note the need to escape the `\`) and will not match lines containing for example `and this is [k]ey\x0value`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I edit to be more clear

Comment: Do you mean `grep '^key\\x0' filename`? Or, if you please, `sed '/^key\\x0/!d' filename`.

Comment: If you need to do matching and printing only it is wise to use grep or egrep....are you matching and doing other stuff like replacement.? as ferdorqui requested..post two samples one before any modifications and one after modification (your expected results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` does not have facilities for matching fixed strings.  One can achieve the same effect, though, by first escaping all the special characters in the string to be matched.  If a key is supplied as the first argument to this script, it will print only the lines in `file` that contain that key:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v script '/^%s\\x00/p' "$(sed 's:[]\[^$.*/]:\\&:g' <<<"$1")"
sed -n "$script" file
```

For more details on this code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770239/3030305).

Comment: Thank you, I feared this anwser.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem as well, and the answer above is insufficient, and actually is specific to the answer that John1024 linked to for more details. It includes the null byte, which isn't applicable here.

To match on a fixed string, you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# These can be anything
OUTER_STRING='hello $( string | is [ a ${ crazy } mess ] like wow; end'
INNER_STRING=' $( string | is [ a ${ crazy } mess ] like wow; en'

# This is the meat and potatoes
CLEAN_SED_STRING="$(echo "$INNER_STRING" | sed 's:[]\[^$.*/]:\\&:g')"
echo "$OUTER_STRING" | sed "s/$CLEAN_SED_STRING/ worl/"
```

To be cleaner, I made a bash function, that obscures the complexity. Tested on OSX, CentOS, RHEL6 and Ubuntu. Only two characters it can't deal with are the null (\x00) and the newline (\x0a)

```bash
function substitute {
    if [[ "$#" == "2" ]] || [[ "$#" == "3" ]]; then
      # Input from stdin
      HAYSTACK="$(/bin/cat -)"
      NEEDLE="$1"
      NEEDLESUB="$2"
      REGEX_FLAGS="$3"
    else
      echo "Usage:   echo <HAYSTACK> | substitute <NEEDLE> <NEEDLESUB> [FLAGS]"
      echo "Example:   echo 'hello w' | substitute 'w' 'world'"
      echo "Example:   echo 'hello w' | substitute 'O' 'xxxxx' 'gi'"
    fi
    CLEAN_SED_STRING="$(echo "$NEEDLE" | sed 's:[]\[^$.*/&]:\\&:g')"
    CLEAN_SED_SUBSTRING="$(echo "$NEEDLESUB" | sed 's:[]\[^$.*/&]:\\&:g')"
    echo "$HAYSTACK" | sed "s/$CLEAN_SED_STRING/$CLEAN_SED_SUBSTRING/$REGEX_FLAGS"
}

# Simple usage
echo 'Hello Arthur' | substitute 'Arthur' 'World'
# Complex usage
echo '/slashes$dollars[square{curly' | substitute '$dollars[' '[]{}()$$'
# Standard piping
echo '
The ghost said "ooooooOOOOOooooooOOO"
The dog said "bork"
' | substitute 'oo' 'ee'
# With global flag and chaining
echo '
The ghost said "ooooooOOOOOooooooOOO"
The dog said "bork"
' | substitute 'oo' 'ee' 'g' | substitute 'ghost' 'siren'
```

Comment: this has side-effects as it overwrites variables. you probably should make them `local` to the function (and while you are there, you could lowercase variable-names that are not envvars)

Comment: there are also a couple of bashisms, that could easily be avoided.